# problema a relacionar tablas con foreign en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cmd

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: Error al poner php artisan migrate]

No se porque dice tabla registro, si registro se llama mi base de datos..

Comment: añade la estructura de todas tus migraciones para poder ayudarte, de otra manera no podemos hacer mucho

Comment: Subi una foto, espero que sea entendible

Comment: de preferencia que sea código, pero de las tres migraciones

Answer (score 2):

Pues el error es simple, Cuando tu creas una llave foranea esta no debe de permitir valores `negativos`, y las tuyas si os permite, así que la solución es sencilla cambia las siguientes lineas:

```
$table->integer("estado_civil");
$table->integer("estudios");
```

POR:

```
$table->integer("estado_civil")->unsigned();
$table->integer("estudios")->unsigned();
```

Espero te sirva.